# the username is correct but password is wrong it doesn't redirect

Tags: php, html, sql-server, sqlsrv

My PHP site is connecting to SQL Server database to then create a session and redirect to the 'dashboard':

- If the username and password is wrong it redirects - works good.
- If the username exists but the password is wrong, it fails to reload ?

Seems so simple but I'm having trouble, help would be great please.

Also suggestions to make this code better would also be good :)

```
<?php

session_start();

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {

        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"WebUIUsers", "UID"=>"DBUser", "PWD"=>"Password1234");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( "sqlserver01", $connectionInfo);

            if( $conn ) {
                // Connection established

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_webui_users WHERE username='$username'";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

                if(!(sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt )) >=1){
                    header("Location: ./index.php");
                }

                // if username exists but password is wrong redirect to try again ?

                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt ) ) {

                        if( $row[password] === $password ) {

                            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $username;
                            header("Location: ./dashboard.php");
                            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
            
                        }else{
                            header("Location: ./index.php");
                        } //end if( $row[password] == $password )

                    } //end while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt ) )

            }else{
                
                echo "Connection to database could not be established.";
                ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

            } //end if( $conn )
 
    } //end if

} // end if

?>
```

Comment: This code is extremely susceptible to [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). You should use [prepared statements with parameter binding](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli).

Comment: Thanks Wesley, gave that a read, will do some editing :)

Comment: Also, you should not be storing passwords in plaintext in a database, instead hash them with a well-regarded library such as `bcrypt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Avoid using Systems Hungarian Notation with database objects (i.e. don't give your tables prefixes like `tbl_` - because `webui_users` could be a `VIEW` or UDF instead of a `BASE TABLE`).

Comment: The actual reason for this unexpected behaviour is that you are calling `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` twice, so `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) { ... }` simply doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тhe actual reason for this unexpected behaviour is that you are calling `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` twice, so `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) { ... }` simply doesn't return any rows.

But you need to consider at least the following:

- Always use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) *... sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.
- Do not store passwords in plaintext in a database.

The following basic example, based on your code, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"WebUIUsers", "UID"=>"DBUser", "PWD"=>"Password1234");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect("sqlserver01", $connectionInfo);
        if ($conn === false) {
            //echo "Connection to database could not be established: ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
            header("Location: ./index.php");
            exit;
        }   

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_webui_users WHERE username = ?";
        $prms = array($username);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $prms);
        if ($stmt === false) {
            //echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
            header("Location: ./index.php");
            exit;
        }   
        
        // User doesn't exists
        if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
            header("Location: ./index.php");
            exit;
        }   
        
        // User exists, but the password is wrong
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt));
        if ($row === false) {
            header("Location: ./index.php");
            exit;
        }   
        if ($row["password"] === $password) {
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $username;
            header("Location: ./dashboard.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: ./index.php");
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov now i have to work on my sql db and secure password storing :)